# Ionic using different default theme colors / define own custom theme default value?

Tags: sass, ionic-framework

ok in `_variables.scss` we have all the definitions. But where can I change away from the setting `light` ? I want to use, say, `royal` or `dark` for all elements.

Do i have to adjust each single element, or is there a single point where I can change that?

e.g.

user `royal` instead of `light` everywhere.

Ok to specify, I see that I can change the theme color of a certain theme here

```
$light:                           #fff !default;
$stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
$positive:                        #387ef5 !default;
$calm:                            #11c1f3 !default;
$balanced:                        #33cd5f !default;
$energized:                       #ffc900 !default;
$assertive:                       #ef473a !default;
$royal:                           #886aea !default;
$dark:                            #444 !default;
```

But where do I set to USE the certain theme colorization? e.g. energized, royal, dark, calm, etc... I want to use something else than light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many [Ionic components](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/) (header, footer, buttons, toggles, list items, ranges, spinners, etc) adding a class of `ELEMENT-color` will change the element to the colors listed in `/scss/ionic.app.scss`. For example:

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
  <h1 class="title">bar-calm</h1>
</div>
```

or...

```
<button class="button button-calm">
  button-calm
</button>
```

or...

```
<ion-spinner class="spinner-calm"></ion-spinner>
```

The above classes will apply the `$calm` color to the components.

For other elements you'll have to find the variable for the element you want to change the color of and override it. The variables you'll be overriding are in `/www/lib/ionic/scss/_variables.scss'.

You can override any variable in that file within `/scss/ionic.app.scss`.

For example:

```
$base-color: $calm;
```

will change the color of many elements to `$calm`.

Comment: that seems like a really sloppy way, how they implemented it.

Comment: There are custom theme generators that might accomplish what you want. No idea if they're compatible with Ionic however. Something like http://www.lavishbootstrap.com/.